# Cannot use static List<String> within Comparator<String>

Tags: java, generics, comparator

Why I have to fully qualify the java.lang.String in the static fields List

```
public static class MyComparator<String> implements Comparator<String> {

        public static List sortOrder;
        public static List<Integer> sortOrder2;
        public static List<java.lang.String> sortOrder3; // works!
        public static List<String> sortOrder4; // <-Compiler error only in this line


        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

            // TODO

            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Error is "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type String"

Answer (score 13):

You have defined a generic type parameter `String` that is the same name as the class, so `String` refers to your parameter, while `java.lang.String` still works.

Remove it from your class, but keep it in the `implements` clause.

```
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
public static class MyComparator<String> implements Comparator<String>
```

to some other distinctive name:

```
public static class MyComparator<S> implements Comparator<String>
```

Comment: But it shoudl be a comparator that compares two java.lang.String objects, used in a SortedMap

Comment: What is the purpose of `S`, when it's supposed to compare `String`s?

Comment: It has no purpose, that is the solution.

Comment: @rgettman well, in this case you're fully right, I'll even upvote your post. All I did is scanned the OP's code without understanding its purpose, but to find the problem.